# How to pass two LINQ joined tables from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have three objects:

```
public class Part
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int descID { get; set; }    
}

public class Description
{
    [Key]
    public int descID { get; set; }
    public string descName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class GridPart
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }            
}
```

I'm using `LINQ` to join Part and Description on the descID column:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    var myParts = from p in db.Parts
                  join d in db.Description on p.descID equals d.DescriptorID
                  select new { Description = d.description, Name = p.name};
    List<GridPart> partsList = new List<GridPart>();

    foreach (var m in myParts)
    {
        GridPart gp = new GridPart();
        gp.Name = m.name;
        gp.description = m.description;                    
        partsList.Add(gp);
    }
    return View(partsList);
}
```

If I was just using the Parts table, in the view I would do:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Part>
```

What do I do if I'm using the joined table?  This uses both Parts and Description, not to mention my List of GridParts, how do I pass this through to display all of the data I need?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass an anonymous type to your view it won't be strongly typed. You can refer to your model like this instead

```
@Html.TextBox("Name")
```

or

```
@Html.Display("Name")
```

Although this will work I would advice against it - The better solution would be to go with a [Viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) instead. This will make your view strongly typed.

Edit: Looking on this again I see that your actually not parsing the anonymous type to your view. Your parsing a list of GridParts.

You should be able to strongly type your view like your tried - just refer to GridParts instead of parts.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.GridPart>
```

Comment: You can use AutoMapper to copy your IQueryable into a ViewModel

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm really new to ASP.net MVC, how would I use a ViewModel in my case?

Comment: Thank your Morten Anderson.  I was getting build errors in VS, after a clean and rebuild, everything is working.